# PageRefresh not working after inserting records into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a function named fillgrid() which fills the grid with data.But it is not getting executed after i call insert() function which inserts records into the database.

Its working fine in my local system.But when i published my solution and put it into the server fillgrid() function is not getting executed.Im not getting any error and i cannot recognize why fillgrid() function is not getting called??

This is my code for insert function.

```
DataTable dtMob = new DataTable();
dtMob = dtMobilizn.Copy();
DataSet dsMobilizn=new DataSet("dsMobilization");
dsMobilizn.Tables.Add(dtMob);
int i = clsMob.InsertMobilizationDetails(dsMobilizn.GetXml());//i am getting the value as 1 when i debugged in local system
if (i != -1)
{
    FillGrid();//This function is not getting called.
}
else
{
    string str = "<script>alert('Cannot mobilize')</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Validation Error", str, false);
    return;
}
```

This is the code for fill grid function.This function is called at the pageload,and is working properly.

```
        DataTable dtGrid = clsMob.GetStandByEmployee(txtSrchEmpCode.Text.Trim());
        if (dtGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ViewState["Sort"] != null)
            {
                DataView dView = new DataView(dtGrid);
                dView.Sort = ViewState["Sort"].ToString();
                gdMobilizn.DataSource = dView;
                gdMobilizn.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                gdMobilizn.DataSource = dtGrid;
                gdMobilizn.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gdMobilizn.DataSource = null;
            gdMobilizn.EmptyDataText = "No Standby Employees Found";
            gdMobilizn.DataBind();
        }
```

This is the function of InsertMobilizationDetails

```
public int InsertMobilizationDetails(string xml)
{
    Database_Operations dbo = new Database_Operations("TransMob_InDetails", true);
    dbo.AddParameter("@xmlMob", xml);        
    return dbo.ExecuteQuery();       
}
```

This is the function of ExecuteQuery

```
public int ExecuteQuery()
    {
        int rowsAffected = -1;
        SqlCon = new SqlConnection();
        using (SqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL_CONNECTION"].ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
                SqlTransaction transaction;
                transaction = SqlCon.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    SqlCmd.Transaction = transaction;
                    rowsAffected = SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();
                    rowsAffected = 1;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    rowsAffected = -1;
                    //Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                rowsAffected = -1;
                //Response.Write(exp.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlCon.Close();
                SqlCon.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Comment: It is hareder for us to diagnose as we can't see what the InsertMobilizationDetails function does...

Comment: post code for clsMob.InsertMobilizationDetails(dsMobilizn.GetXml());

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint next to 

if (i != -1)to see what the value of i is? What does -1 represent? nothing added?

Also, have you stepped into 

clsMob.InsertMobilizationDetails(dsMobilizn.GetXml());to see if this is giving the expected result?

Comment: Yes as i've said above,fillgrid is working properly after insertion in local system.When i published the solution and placed it on the server,the problem comes

Answer (score 0):

Check for Ispostback property inside the pageload event.Put the method inside !ispostback.

may be this works for you.